# node child_process not executing more that one command on mac but working fine with windows

Tags: node.js, macos, command, exec, child-process

I have written node child_process exec for cloning the code from repo and then doing npm install on that folder. Everything is working fine with windows machine but not with mac machine. It also works fine when the command is given through cmd prompt. How can this be resolved.

```
var projectSetup = myexec("git clone http://127.0.0.1/username/projectName.git & cd projectName & sudo npm install");
projectSetup.on("exit", function(data) {
    console.log("Exit "+ data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Windows command the `&` character separates commands that are to be run sequentially, so on Windows your `git clone` will complete before `cd` is executed and `npm` is executed after `cd` completes.  Presumably that's what you want to happen.

However, on Mac `&` means "run the preceding command as a background process and immediately execute the following command, without waiting for the first command to finish".  Therefore on Mac all three commands in that line will execute simultaneously as separate independent processes, and even if the `cd` command succeeds it will not establish a new working directory for the `npm` command.  So something will happen, but the result won't be what you wanted.

The equivalent of the Windows `&` separator on Mac is the `;` character, so one solution would be to build and execute a different command string for each platform.  (The JavaScript string join() method will be useful if decide to do this.)

An alternative is to take advantage of the fact that both Windows and Mac understand the `&&` separator, which means "execute the next command only after the previous one completes successfully".  So you could change `&` to `&&` in your command string and that should work on both platforms, with the added benefit that if something goes wrong (for example, if the `git clone` fails) then you won't do additional work that might pollute your directory tree (like running `npm install` in the original parent directory if the `projectName` directory was not created).

Comment: Thank you so much for so quick response. It resolved my issue :)